# How to get method name of a static class in runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

How to get all methods name in a static class like `Math` ?

Output should be similar to following :

```
Sin
Cos
Round
...
```

Comment: Have you tried with this System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();

Comment: @coder I don't want the current method. I want all methods which exist in class `Math`

Comment: Do you want this at runtime or design time?

Comment: @JohnWillemse Runtime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
    MethodInfo[] methodInfos = typeof(Math).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in methodInfos)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(methodInfo.Name);
    }
```

Addtionally if you need to know all the parameters too, try something like

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        MethodInfo[] methodInfos = typeof(Math).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in methodInfos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} with following parameters", methodInfo.Name));
            ParameterInfo[] parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
            foreach (ParameterInfo parameter in parameters)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name : {0}, Type : {1}", parameter.Name, parameter.ParameterType.FullName);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("--------------");
        }
    }
```

The output :

```
Acos with following parameters
Name : d, Type : System.Double

--------------
Asin with following parameters
Name : d, Type : System.Double

--------------
Atan with following parameters
Name : d, Type : System.Double

--------------
Atan2 with following parameters
Name : y, Type : System.Double
Name : x, Type : System.Double

--------------
Ceiling with following parameters
Name : d, Type : System.Decimal

--------------
Ceiling with following parameters
Name : a, Type : System.Double

--------------
Cos with following parameters
Name : d, Type : System.Double

--------------
Cosh with following parameters
Name : value, Type : System.Double

--------------
Floor with following parameters
Name : d, Type : System.Decimal

--------------
Floor with following parameters
Name : d, Type : System.Double

--------------
Sin with following parameters
Name : a, Type : System.Double

--------------
Tan with following parameters
Name : a, Type : System.Double

--------------
Sinh with following parameters
Name : value, Type : System.Double

--------------
Tanh with following parameters
Name : value, Type : System.Double

--------------
Round with following parameters
Name : a, Type : System.Double

--------------
Round with following parameters
Name : value, Type : System.Double
Name : digits, Type : System.Int32

--------------
Round with following parameters
Name : value, Type : System.Double
Name : mode, Type : System.MidpointRounding

--------------
Round with following parameters
Name : value, Type : System.Double
Name : digits, Type : System.Int32
Name : mode, Type : System.MidpointRounding

--------------
Round with following parameters
Name : d, Type : System.Decimal

--------------
Round with following parameters
Name : d, Type : System.Decimal
Name : decimals, Type : System.Int32

--------------
Round with following parameters
Name : d, Type : System.Decimal
Name : mode, Type : System.MidpointRounding

--------------
Round with following parameters
Name : d, Type : System.Decimal
Name : decimals, Type : System.Int32
Name : mode, Type : System.MidpointRounding

--------------
Truncate with following parameters
Name : d, Type : System.Decimal

--------------
Truncate with following parameters
Name : d, Type : System.Double

--------------
Sqrt with following parameters
Name : d, Type : System.Double

--------------
Log with following parameters
Name : d, Type : System.Double

--------------
Log10 with following parameters
Name : d, Type : System.Double

--------------
Exp with following parameters
Name : d, Type : System.Double

--------------
Pow with following parameters
Name : x, Type : System.Double
Name : y, Type : System.Double

--------------
IEEERemainder with following parameters
Name : x, Type : System.Double
Name : y, Type : System.Double

--------------
Abs with following parameters
Name : value, Type : System.SByte

--------------
Abs with following parameters
Name : value, Type : System.Int16

--------------
Abs with following parameters
Name : value, Type : System.Int32

--------------
Abs with following parameters
Name : value, Type : System.Int64

--------------
Abs with following parameters
Name : value, Type : System.Single

--------------
Abs with following parameters
Name : value, Type : System.Double

--------------
Abs with following parameters
Name : value, Type : System.Decimal

--------------
Max with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.SByte
Name : val2, Type : System.SByte

--------------
Max with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.Byte
Name : val2, Type : System.Byte

--------------
Max with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.Int16
Name : val2, Type : System.Int16

--------------
Max with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.UInt16
Name : val2, Type : System.UInt16

--------------
Max with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.Int32
Name : val2, Type : System.Int32

--------------
Max with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.UInt32
Name : val2, Type : System.UInt32

--------------
Max with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.Int64
Name : val2, Type : System.Int64

--------------
Max with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.UInt64
Name : val2, Type : System.UInt64

--------------
Max with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.Single
Name : val2, Type : System.Single

--------------
Max with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.Double
Name : val2, Type : System.Double

--------------
Max with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.Decimal
Name : val2, Type : System.Decimal

--------------
Min with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.SByte
Name : val2, Type : System.SByte

--------------
Min with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.Byte
Name : val2, Type : System.Byte

--------------
Min with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.Int16
Name : val2, Type : System.Int16

--------------
Min with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.UInt16
Name : val2, Type : System.UInt16

--------------
Min with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.Int32
Name : val2, Type : System.Int32

--------------
Min with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.UInt32
Name : val2, Type : System.UInt32

--------------
Min with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.Int64
Name : val2, Type : System.Int64

--------------
Min with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.UInt64
Name : val2, Type : System.UInt64

--------------
Min with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.Single
Name : val2, Type : System.Single

--------------
Min with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.Double
Name : val2, Type : System.Double

--------------
Min with following parameters
Name : val1, Type : System.Decimal
Name : val2, Type : System.Decimal

--------------
Log with following parameters
Name : a, Type : System.Double
Name : newBase, Type : System.Double

--------------
Sign with following parameters
Name : value, Type : System.SByte

--------------
Sign with following parameters
Name : value, Type : System.Int16

--------------
Sign with following parameters
Name : value, Type : System.Int32

--------------
Sign with following parameters
Name : value, Type : System.Int64

--------------
Sign with following parameters
Name : value, Type : System.Single

--------------
Sign with following parameters
Name : value, Type : System.Double

--------------
Sign with following parameters
Name : value, Type : System.Decimal

--------------
BigMul with following parameters
Name : a, Type : System.Int32
Name : b, Type : System.Int32

--------------
DivRem with following parameters
Name : a, Type : System.Int32
Name : b, Type : System.Int32
Name : result, Type : System.Int32&

--------------
DivRem with following parameters
Name : a, Type : System.Int64
Name : b, Type : System.Int64
Name : result, Type : System.Int64&

--------------
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [`.GetMembers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmembers%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
var list = typeof(Math).GetMembers().Select(c => c.Name).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Good alternative however this return members which includes (properties, methods, fields, events, and so on).

Comment: @Mahdi we can do that in one single line `:)`